# tf.distribute.Strategy: TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.distribute.values.PerReplica'> to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing

Judging on the examples on the TensorFlow website: https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.15/site/en/guide/distribute_strategy.ipynb, it seems there are no resources on how to adapt your code to using distribute strategy. My original code includes manipulating Tensors, for example `tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)`. However, when distribute strategy is used, I got the abovementioned error as `expand_dims()` is not able to work on `PerReplica` object. More details of the error below:

> Contents: PerReplica:{
>     0 /replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(?, 2, 3), dtype=float32, device=/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0),
>     1 /replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_1:0", shape=(?, 2, 3), dtype=float32, device=/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1)
>   }

Anyone has any idea to any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

`PerReplica` object is usually returned by running `strategy.experimental_run_v2/run(...)`, you can think it as a special dict that wraps these message pairs together:
{i-th GPU name: tensors returned by i-th GPU},for i in your all available devices. It looks like a dict but not a real dict, class `PerReplica` defines additional methods/properties [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8d25e4bf616b7ae4ed101c580a23421616bf674c/tensorflow/python/distribute/values.py#L332) for many use cases, e.g, reduce tensors cross devices under distributed context. For your case:

```
 x = strategy.experimental_run_v2(...)
 if strategy.num_replicas_in_sync > 1:  # x is PerReplica object for multi-devices
    tensors_list = x.values             # a list [x_from_dev_a, x_from_dev_b, ...]
    y = tf.concat(tensors_list, axis=0) # axis=0 at batch dim
 else:
    y = x      # x is a tensor as it is for single device

 tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the simple solution. I am using tf 2.2 and it works like charm -- but if we can access the values from `PerReplica` object using `.values` attribute, what is the use of `strategy.reduce` functionality that TensorFlow provides? We can easily reduce the outputs by ourselves!